# Intellij Idea does not display javac compiler warnings of referencing proprietary API

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-warnings, javac

I'm working with Intellij Idea 10 and Java 6 JDK Update 7. When I run `Build --> Rebuild Project` command, the javac compilation (using parameter `-Xlint:all`) displays warnings, but for some reason does not include warnings about the source code referencing Sun proprietary API classes.

When I run javac (yes, the same version that is referenced from Idea) manually from the command line, I can see those warnings all right. And I would like to see the same information in Idea as well. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. Could be that IDEA doesn't support some of the warning types and doesn't report them. Please [submit an issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) with the sample project attached.